# Можно ли сократить запись на python

Tags: python

Для цикла

```
for(int i=1; i<10; i++) на язык C++
```

аналогичным на языке python будет запись:

```
i = 10
while i<10:
    i+=1
```

Или есть более простая запись на python?

Comment: Аналогичным будет `for i in range(1, 10):`

Comment: только для аналога надо хотя бы `i = 1` сделать :)

Answer (score 5):

На python можно воспользоваться циклом for и в нем, с помощью функции range() перебирать все значения от 1 до 10:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print(i)
```

Вывод этого кода будет таким:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```